# iperf3 on ESXi 7.0.2 does not work?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

On ESXi 6.7 EP15 there's `/usr/lib/vmware/vsan/bin/iperf3.copy` and it works fine. On ESX 7.0 u2d there's only `/usr/lib/vmware/vsan/bin/iperf3` and it stopped working for me.

```
$ esxcli network firewall set -e off
$ /usr/lib/vmware/vsan/bin/iperf3 -s
iperf3: error - unable to start listener for connections: Operation not permitted
iperf3: exiting
$
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just create a copy of iperf3 before start it with -s options.

Comment: cool it works. esx is magic.